# Post Branded Content to Facebook Page Feed Using the Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Ever since Facebook's [Branded Content](https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/get-started/branded-content) announcement, I've been trying to figure out how to post Branded Content to a Verified Facebook Page's Feed via API. This is a requirement for my company, as we post what now qualifies as Branded Content directly to a Facebook Page's Feed via the `POST /{page_id}/feed` endpoint.

The user flow that we're now trying to automate would be accomplished for example, by

1. pasting a link in the Page Composer text field
2. clicking the "handshake" icon
3. searching for the third-party sponsor, selecting that sponsor
4. publishing the post

On the Branded Content page they mention that this can be accomplished through their Marketing API,

> Read the Marketing API documentation to learn about using the branded
>   content tool through the API.

but everything I've seen in the documentation seems to indicate that I need to create an Ad Campaign, then an Ad Set, then specify Targetting, then create the Ad Creative, then the Ad itself. I saw only one example on the Ad Creative Reference section that [seems to be what I'm looking for](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative),

```
curl \
  -F 'name=Sample Creative' \
  -F 'object_story_spec={ 
    "page_id": "<PAGE_ID>", 
    "photo_data": { 
      "branded_content_sponsor_page_id": "<SPONSOR_PAGE_ID>", 
      "caption": "My caption", 
      "image_hash": "<IMAGE_HASH>" 
    } 
  }' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives
```

The item of note is the 'branded_content_sponsor_page_id' field, which I think would cover the Handshake Icon/with {sponsor} field.

My conclusion so far is thus:

1. The inclusion of the Targetting in particular seems to mean that if this is the direction we're supposed to go, then the Ad would not have normal visibility like a post to a Page's Feed. In addition, instead of one POST to `/{page_id}/feed`, we would have to create all of the supporting Ad objects, then the Creative, then the Ad, then have the post reviewed. Or...
2. the functionality that I'm looking for is not documented yet, or...
3. the functionality that I'm looking for does not exist

Comment: Hi @Andrew, did you figure out if this functionality exists??

Comment: @Dap, sorry for the late reply, it seems that for my purposes, I did not need to go about creating posts in this manner. I've spoken with a colleague about the process a while ago and it seems that my speculation about the sponsor_page_id field was correct; however, I don't have specific as I never had to get any working code for this.